# Deserialize a vector written with debug trait formatting

Tags: rust, deserialization

Given a simple vector of vectors of `usize`, I can leverage the fact that `Vec` implements the `Debug` trait, and therefore use the `{:?}` formatter to pretty-print it (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72b09a58a863a9ead16b8c2ce02ac19a)):

```rust
let mut hierarchy: Vec<Vec<usize>> = Vec::new();
hierarchy.push(vec![0,1,2,3]);
hierarchy.push(vec![0,1]);
println!("Hierarchy: {:?}", hierarchy);
```

Assume that I write the output of `println!(...)` to a file. How can I easily deserialize it later?

E.g. my file looks like this:

```
[[0,1,2,3],[0,1]]
```

Using [`serde`](https://serde.rs/), I could serialize my data type and store it as (for example) JSON file. However, I don't need any "fancy" data format, just this plain vector of vectors. Is there any easy solution to deserialize according to the `Debug` trait ("reverse the printing")? Is there a simpler option than having to do all of the parser logic by hand, e.g. reading the file character by character looking for `[`, `]` and `,`?

Comment: debug trait was meant to be human readable, not machine readable. therefore, I think the best bet is use a format that is designed to be read by machines (and has a library that does it for you) like JSON as you mentioned

Comment: Calling JSON "fancy" makes me wonder what you consider unsophisticated. It's *extremely* basic for arrays.

Comment: @tadman I forgot that [JSON](https://www.json.org/) also permits an array as root element. I didn't want to have an object like { "hierarchy": [ [0,1,2,3],[0,1] ] }, that's why I called it "fancy" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use the `Debug` trait for this purpose. It offers no guarantees that it is parseable, or that it is useful for any purpose at all.

> Derived `Debug` formats are not stable, and so may change with future Rust versions. Additionally, `Debug` implementations of types provided by the standard library (`std`, `core`, `alloc`, etc.) are not stable, and may also change with future Rust versions.

— [`std::fmt::Debug` trait documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html)

There have been, for example, proposals for a compilation option that would make `Debug` never print anything at all, to avoid generating formatting code when code size is a priority. That might or might not ever happen, but it's *allowed* to happen; (Unfortunately I can't find a link to the recent one I remember; [this is an older one](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/option-to-turn-debug-into-no-op/17587).)

---

`serde_json` is a perfectly good way to solve this problem:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut hierarchy: Vec<Vec<usize>> = Vec::new();
    hierarchy.push(vec![0, 1, 2, 3]);
    hierarchy.push(vec![0, 1]);
    serde_json::to_writer(std::io::stdout(), &hierarchy).unwrap();
}
```

will print `[[0,1,2,3],[0,1]]`. You don't need any setup.

If you care about using more Rust-like syntax, you can use [`ron`](https://docs.rs/ron/latest/ron/), a general purpose serializer that uses a Rust-like notation; or [`uneval`](https://docs.rs/uneval/latest/uneval/) which generates *actual Rust code*, but you'll need a Rust compiler to "deserialize" it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have looked into the `Debug` trait to realize the stability issue. Also, I forgot that JSON allows arrays as root element (instead of objects `{...}`), so the way with `serde_json` is perfectly fine for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

`Debug` is specifically intended to only be for printing. If a type can be easily parsed, it will implement `FromStr`, and this will often be compatible with the type's implementation of `Display`. `Vec` does not do this. From a computer science perspective, reversing a function is not generally possible, and even reversing specific functions requires substantial language support that Rust (and virtually all languages) doesn't provide. The answer to your last question is no: the simplest option is to parse it by hand.

There is a serialization format specifically designed to look like `Debug`: [RON](https://docs.rs/ron/). If you want your output to be both familiar and machine readable, then RON is a good choice. RON also happens to match your current `Debug` output, so if you have any existing files you can use them without conversion.

You can replace your `println!` calls with RON like this:

```rs
// You can reuse this for later prints
let stdout = std::io::stdout();
// This block ensures the lock is dropped
{
    use std::io::Write;
    let mut lock = stdout.lock();
    ron::ser::to_writer(&mut lock, &hierarchy).unwrap();
    writeln!(lock).unwrap();
}
```

You could put this in a function for convenience.